# What's value should I put in KEY_NAME of fingerprint authentication in android studio?

Tags: android

I have been finished the code of my project but when I reach to this step, I don't know what should I do, or what is I give a value to this parameter?

[image]

Comment: its for a key-value pair, read: [key-value pair](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) and [fingerprint auth](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html#fingerprint-authentication)

Comment: please click on "please help me!!", it's contain a picture. tell me what should I give a value for this?

Answer (score 1):

That parameter is used in `Builder` class of **[KeyGenParameterSpec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder.html#KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(java.lang.String,int))**

```
//Specify the operation(s) this key can be used for//
KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_NAME,
KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT |
    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
.setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
//Configure this key so that the user has to confirm their identity with a fingerprint each time they want to use it//
  .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
  .setEncryptionPaddings(
   KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
.build());
```

Later on you can get key using:

```
 SecretKey key = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME, null);
```

Thank you.